# Access Class Method / Function PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have an *index.php* and a *Regions.php* which is a class. I'm trying to call a method from  Regions class to my *index.php* but it seems I can't access it.It says:

`Call to undefined function getRegionInfo() in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercise4\index.php on line 7`

But I already included the files I need. Here's the code.

```
index.php

$regions = new Regions;
$regions = getRegionInfo();
$regions = get_regions();
```

Here's my Region class

```
class Regions
{

 public function getRegionInfo()
 {
    $this->get_regions();
 }

 private function get_regions()
 {
    global $db;
    $result = array();
    $sql  = "SELECT RegionID, RegionName, IslandID FROM ref_regions";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
      array_push($result,array($row['RegionID'], $row['RegionName'], $row['IslandID']));
    }     
    return $result;
 }

}
```

Comment: Include the file in include.php `include_once("Regions.php");`

Comment: You need to study how OOP works.

Answer (score 3):

First, the correct index.php would look something like this:

```
$regionObj = new Regions();
$regions = $regionObj->getRegionInfo();
```

You need to indicate that you're calling the `getRegionInfo` function on a specific instance of the `Regions` object (`$regionsObj` in the example above).

Second, there is no point in creating a public and a private method in this case.  Including the extra private method is unnecessary because all the public method does is call the private method.  Just put all the code in the public method.  You could just have:

```
class Regions
{

 public function getRegionInfo()
 {
    global $db;
    $result = array();
    $sql  = "SELECT RegionID, RegionName, IslandID FROM ref_regions";
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
      array_push($result,array($row['RegionID'], $row['RegionName'], $row['IslandID']));
    }     
    return $result;
 }

}
```

Third, you shouldn't have your `$db` be a global variable.  Instead, send it as a parameter to the constructor of your `Regions` class:

```
class Regions
{

 private $database;

 public function __construct(PDO $database) {
     $this->database = $database;
 }

 public function getRegionInfo()
 {
    $result = array();
    $sql  = "SELECT RegionID, RegionName, IslandID FROM ref_regions";
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
    {
      array_push($result,array($row['RegionID'], $row['RegionName'], $row['IslandID']));
    }     
    return $result;
 }

}
```

Then create the Regions object like this:

```
$regionsObj = new Regions($db);
```

Fourth, you don't need to populate the results array yourself.  Instead, you can just return the results of the `fetchAll` function on your `$stmt` object:

```
 public function getRegionInfo()
 {
    $sql  = "SELECT RegionID, RegionName, IslandID FROM ref_regions";
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
 }
```

Your final class, with all the changes, will look like this:

```
class Regions
{

 private $database;

 public function __construct(PDO $database) {
     $this->database = $database;
 }

 public function getRegionInfo()
 {
    $sql  = "SELECT RegionID, RegionName, IslandID FROM ref_regions";
    $stmt = $this->database->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $stmt->fetchAll();
 }

}
```

A final note, I'm not sure if you just didn't include this portion of your code, and this was mentioned in another answer, I'll include it here just to be complete, make sure to include your `Regions.php` file in `index.php` before referencing the `Regions` class:

```
include_once("Regions.php");
```

Comment: Two things I'd change; 1) type hint the `PDO` instance, ie `__construct(PDO $database)`, and 2) a simple `return $stmt->fetchAll()` is neater

Comment: @Phil Good suggestions.  I added them.

Comment: Smaller really does look better. You could shave another line or two off by using `return $this->database->query('SELECT ...')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` ;)

Comment: @Phil I gotta leave some room for the OP to grow on his/her own  :)

Comment: I am getting Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_VARIABLE in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercise4\inc\Model\Regions.php on line 7 . I think it is on the contructor?

Comment: Fatal error: Cannot use object of type Regions as array in C:\xampp\htdocs\exercise4\index.php on line 14

Comment: @JoeneFloresca Sorry, forgot to include `function` in the constructor definition.  See edited version.

Comment: @JoeneFloresca You should probably post the issues you're having with the `Cannot use object of type Regions as array` error as a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

Class Methods are accessed by using the `->`symbol. So use:

```
$regions = new Regions();
$regions->getRegionInfo();
$regions->get_regions();
```

And change your `get_regions()` from private to public, if you want to call it externally.

Comment: protected methods can't be called "externally" either.

Comment: Why make it protected at all?  Just don't call it "externally", it's unnecessary.

Comment: Because calling `getRegionInfo()` is the same as calling `get_regions();` in this case. And pls remove my downvotes folks. è.é

Comment: `getRegionInfo()` calls `get_regions()`, so `get_regions` can stay private; just remove your third line (`$regions->get_regions();`), it's not necessary

Comment: Firstly, the OP already makes this extra call, and can find out for themselves that private means private. Secondly, the original code doesn't actually return anything from the public method. This answers the question directly asked, so doesn't deserve downvotes IMHO.

Comment: Cully, `getRegionInfo()` only contains `$this->get_regions();` so there is no point of doing it this way unless code changes.

Answer (score 0):

How about this.. You need to include_once the file before you can use it

index.php

```
include_once("Regions.php");

$regions = new Regions;
$x = $regions->getRegionInfo(); //this is temp var name
```

Comment: small fix `return $this->get_regions();`

Comment: OP says they've already included the files. I'd say the problem is due to the lack of instance prefix which you (`$regions->getRegionInfo()`) and @Lashane (`return $this->get_regions()`) have addressed

Comment: @JoeneFloresca You need to do this --- $regions->getRegionInfo()